# PHP.ini override isues on CentOS 7 / PHP 5.6

Tags: centos7, php5, php.ini

I wanted to increase my servers upload_max_filesize, so I downloaded the PHP.ini file from /etc/ made the change locally and then uploaded the file via FTP.

During the upload the FileZilla mentioned that I was overriding the file on the server with my local copy, the difference in filesize was significant (which it shouldn't have been), something in the region of 67kb > 25kb.

After the upload, I've completely lost control of the installation. For instance the following command:

`sudo chown -R ec2-user /ect/`

Resulted in the following:

```
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is owned by uid 500, should be 0
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 500, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I'm not sure what I've done. I've clearly overridden the wrong file. Maybe I override a shortcut or a file in a shortcut.

Any suggestions on how to recover the mystery file?

Comment: As a note - this is a dev environment I use for checking solutions before carrying them out in a live environment.

Comment: You've pretty well screwed your instance. Restore a backup from a snapshot or start a new instance. Then don't run that command again.

Comment: Thanks, I figured as much. I'll have a look at the last snapshot I ran. Not had to restore from one before.